# How do I reach my local development server (127.0.0.1) with a domain name (e.g. www.mydomain.example)

Tags: dns

web newbie here, I need to do some testing so I need to reach my development server (127.0.0.1 on Mac OS X) with a 'real' domian name (e.g. www.mydomain.example). any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it's for your machine only, manipulating the `hosts` file is the best option.

Add the following line to it:

```
127.0.0.1    www.mydomain.com
```

where it is located depends on your OS. If on Windows, do a search for `hosts` in `C:\Windows\system32`

You may have to restart your browser for it to take effect.

Comment: On Windows the `hosts` file is generally located in `C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc`. On Ubuntu you can find it in `/etc`.

Comment: -1 127.0.0.1 is loopback ip address for each individual machines

Check this http://compnetworking.about.com/od/workingwithipaddresses/g/127_0_0_1_def.htm

Comment: @Sandy I know. So what? It is perfectly possible and legal to map arbitrary domain names to the local address. What is the problem here?

Comment: @Pekka.. hm.. i thought he was looking to access production server in LAN

Comment: Hi, do you know where it's located on linux? (I'm working with mac...)

Comment: @apple see @Nalum's comment - `/etc/hosts` it should be.

Comment: I did it but it doesn't seem to work. I even restarted my computer.. Should I do anything else?

Comment: @apple What does the exact line look like?

Comment: it's on my /etc/hosts (maybe it should be in /usr/etc/hosts, I don't know..) and it's
127.0.0.1:8000 www.mbatour.co.il